# How to NSLog a CGRect

Tags: objective-c

I am trying to see some properties of a CGRect and doing:

```
NSLog(@"%@", frame);
```

However, I get an error that says `CGRect` is not an `id` type. How would I print the frame to see attributes of it?

Answer (score 130):

You need to use `NSStringFromCGRect` which will convert the `CG structs` into `NSString`, Refer below:-

```
NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromCGRect(frame));
```

Also below are the following other functions which can be used for `NSLog` `CG Structs` as well:-

```
NSStringFromCGPoint  
NSStringFromCGSize  
NSStringFromCGRect  
NSStringFromCGAffineTransform  
NSStringFromUIEdgeInsets
```

Comment: Use :
NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromCGPoint(point));